# Should the popular answer be accepted if you do not use/test it?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette

A while back, I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183158/is-it-possible-to-use-the-drupal-api-to-get-a-list-of-users).  I did not test the answer because the project was abandoned shortly after asking it.  There are good responses - they just are not useful to me.  It feels rude not to accept an answer when people took the time to respond.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I've often wondered this myself.

Answer (score 3):

Did the popular answer help you more than any other answer? Did you learn something from it even though you didn't implement it? If so, I'd say it's okay to go ahead and award that checkmark.